# Should I use component function or useEffect hook to get value based on multiple props?

Tags: reactjs

These two Tooltip components do the same thing, using different methods.

Which method makes more sense? If it's the hook why is that better?

```js
const Tooltip = (props) => {
  const isVisible = () => {
    return props.conditionOne && props.conditionTwo;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {isVisible() && (
        <div>I am visible!</div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

vs.

```js
const Tooltip = (props) => {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsVisible(props.conditionOne && props.conditionTwo);
  }, [props.conditionOne, props.conditionTwo]);

  return (
    <div>
      {isVisible && (
        <div>I am visible!</div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Both will recalculate the value on each component change, but in the second example the value will also be saved in state. I'm not sure, you need it there